# Assigning a 2D byte array and accessing via Web3

Tags: solidity, dapp-development, truffle, arrays

So I'm trying to work with two-dimensional byte arrays and am experiencing some results that I don't quite understand. I am using [Truffle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle) v2.0.4 for compiling/deploying my contracts with [ethereumjs-testrpc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-testrpc) as a blockchain backend.

Consider this super simple contract. It initilizes a 2D array of bytes, assigns the third element in the first array, and returns:

```
contract Sandbox {

    function retArr() 
    public constant returns (byte[3][10] ret) {
        ret[0][2] = byte(2);
    }

}
```

I can then access this contract via Truffle's Web3 wrapper:

```
Sandbox.deployed().retArr().then(function(res) {
    console.log(res)
})
```

Which produces the following output:

```
[ [ '0x00', '0x00', '0x02' ],
  [ '0x00', '0x02', '0x00' ],
  [ '0x02', '0x00', '0x00' ],
  [ '0x00', '0x00', '0x00' ],
  [ '0x00', '0x00', '0x00' ],
  [ '0x00', '0x00', '0x00' ],
  [ '0x00', '0x00', '0x00' ],
  [ '0x00', '0x00', '0x00' ],
  [ '0x00', '0x00', '0x00' ],
  [ '0x00', '0x00', '0x00' ] ]
```

The first child array looks correct (`0x02` is assigned to the third position), but then `0x02` pops up in the second and third arrays as well.

Why did multiple elements get assigned with one call? If this is expected behavior, what's the rationale behind this design decision? How can I only assign one element at a time in a 2D array?

Comment: to be honest, it seems to me like a bug in web3 byte two dimensional array decoding:

1. It works fine with address[16][16] which I use.

2. I have a proposed fix that works for your case, but I've yet to generalize it.

Comment: since eventually, byte (=bytes1) is padded to 32 bytes, a quick workaround for you would be to return bytes32[3][10] instead

Comment: It could very well be a bug in web3. Maybe I should open an issue on Github? And thanks for the `bytes32` suggestion, I'll play around with that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Features#in-memory-types) that:

> If possible (i.e. from anything to memory and from anything to a
>   storage reference that is not a pointer), conversions between these
>   data locations are performed automatically by the compiler. Sometimes,
>   this is still not possible, i.e. mappings cannot reside in memory (as
>   their size is unknown) and for now, some types in memory are not yet
>   implemented, this includes structs and multi-dimensional arrays.

This is probably the reason.

Comment: The answer probably rests somewhere between a lack of implementation in Solidity and/or a decoding bug in Web3 (as @kobigurk had suggested). Also, thanks for that awesome link! :D